# Can I connect a native application to a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I was wondering if it is possible to connect a host application to a chrome extension. I am interested to know if the communication can be made precisely this way: host -> extension.

Comment: The only method is [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) API, which starts a host app from an extension.

Comment: So the other way around is not possible? I don't want the extension to start the application, but the application to connect to the extension from time to time.